# Modify FTP default Internet Explorer page

Tags: iis, ftp, webserver, ftp-server, iis-manager

I am trying to find the default page of the FTP webpage, as the one shown in 
below:

[image]

How I can modify this page, or which HTML file / or FTP attribute I should change to get my needs?

Another thing, how I can add a link to that page to allow users to upload or add users, such that the users will not be created as a local computer users?

Can that happen? If yes could you guide me to the required tips that I should follow?

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The page is not coming from the FTP server. It's just how the Internet Explorer renders the FTP directory listing.

You cannot change it server-side.

If you open the same `ftp://` URL in another browser (Firefox, Chrome, ...), you will see a different "page".

---

You would have to implement a web application with your desired custom layout that does the FTP behind the scenes.